# UIDatePicker set time does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker, dateformatter

I am trying to set the time for UIDatePicker from the text of UITextField. But it always gets reset to current time. Text on UITextField is 14:01 and this is how I am trying to set time on UIDatePicker :

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
let time = formatter.date(from: textField.text!)
datePickerTime.date = time!
```

This is is the initialisation of **datePickerTime** :

```
datePickerTime = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(210), width: CGFloat(320), height: CGFloat(216)))
datePickerTime.datePickerMode = .time
datePickerTime.minimumDate = Date()
```

I have tried similar case with setting date(not time) and it works fine.

Comment: where u called on both methods

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : Date picker initialisation is in viewDidLoad and I am setting datePicker time in textFieldShouldBeginEditing

Comment: called in `textFieldendEditing` and `textfieldSholdReturn`

Comment: at the same time set `datePickerTime. date = Date() also

Comment: your problem is resolved or not bro

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : Sorry Anbu, it didn't work.

Comment: Guess: `let time = formatter.date(from: textField.text!)` isn't good. Check its value, my guess is that's it's not from today, but an old day, and it could explain why it doesn't change.